# undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class when trying to create a record in my database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

Ive got a problem with my Rails app.

When I try to create a new `client` in my `clients` table im getting this error => `undefined method model_name for NilClass:Class`

It's telling me the error is in my show view at line #2.

```
1: <%- model_class = @client.class -%>
2: <h1><%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human %></h1>
3: 
4: <p>
5:   <strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:name) %>:</strong><br>
```

Heres my show view..

```
<%- model_class = @client.class -%>
<h1><%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human %></h1>

<p>
  <strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:name) %>:</strong><br>
  <%= @client.name %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:detail) %>:</strong><br>
  <%= @client.detail %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:more_detail) %>:</strong><br>
  <%= @client.more_detail %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:more_details) %>:</strong><br>
  <%= @client.more_details %>
</p>

<div class="form-actions">
  <%= link_to t('.back', :default => t("helpers.links.back")),
              clients_path, :class => 'btn'  %>
  <%= link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
              edit_client_path(@client), :class => 'btn' %>
  <%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
              client_path(@client),
              :method => 'delete',
              :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')),
              :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
</div>
```

Here's my controller =>

> class ClientsController < ApplicationController
>
> ```
>   respond_to :html
>
>   def index
>     @clients = Client.all
>     respond_with (@clients)
>   end
>
>   def new
>     @clients = Client.new
>     respond_with (@clients)
>   end
>
>   def create
>     @clients = Client.new(params[:name])
>     if @clients.save
>       flash[:notice] = "Client successfully created"
>     end
>     respond_with(@clients)
>   end
>
>   def destroy
>   @clients = Client.find(params[:id])
>   @clients.destroy
>   flash[:notice] = "Client has been removed."
>   respond_with(@clients)
>   end
>
> end
> ```

I can't see where the problem is?

Ive recently installed the rails-twitter-bootstrap gem but don't think that would effect it much.

Comment: Have you done a `rake db:migrate` after creating the model?

Comment: yes my migration was done when I generated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting in your controller the value of `@clients` (with `s` at the end) and accessing in your view just the `@client` variable, i.e. without `s`. Fix this.